# Trying to write a memoized solution to largest common substring that is not working

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I have written this memoized solution to LCS, but it doesn't seem to be working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
const lcsMemo = (s1, s2) => {
    let i = 0, j = 0
    const memo = Array.from(new Array(s1.length), () => Array(s2.length).fill(''))
    console.log(memo);


    const helper = (s1, s2, i, j, memo) => {
        if (i === s1.length || j === s2.length) return 0

        if (memo[i][j]) return memo[i][j]

        if (s1[i] === s2[j]) {
            return 1 + helper(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1, memo)
        }

        else {
            return memo[i][j] = Math.max(helper(s1, s2, i + 1, j, memo), helper(s1, s2, i, j + 1, memo))
        }
    }
    return helper(s1, s2, i, j, memo)
}
```

I am including it in this function to solve a HackerRank problem called common child.  I have 9/15 tests passing, however the tests that are failing of which I can't view are failing with the message runtime error. The runtime error from the HackerRank site says this about the error:

```
Your code terminated unexpectedly. Did you overrun your array? Is your code trying to divide by zero?
```

```
const commonChild = (s1, s2) => {
    const arr1 = [],
        arr2 = []


    for (let [i, letter] of [...s1].entries()) {
        let index = s2.indexOf(letter)
        if (index > -1) {
            arr1.push(letter)
        }
    }
    for (let [i, letter] of [...s2].entries()) {
        let index = s1.indexOf(letter)
        if (index > -1) {
            arr2.push(letter)
        }
    }

    console.log(arr1.join(''));
    console.log(arr2.join(''));

    const lcsMemo = (s1, s2) => {
        let i = 0, j = 0
        const memo = Array.from(new Array(s1.length), () => Array(s2.length).fill(''))

        const helper = (s1, s2, i, j, memo) => {
            if (i === s1.length || j === s2.length) return 0

            if (memo[i][j]) return memo[i][j]

            if (s1[i] === s2[j]) {
                return 1 + helper(s1, s2, i + 1, j + 1, memo)
            }

            else {
                return memo[i][j] = Math.max(helper(s1, s2, i + 1, j, memo), helper(s1, s2, i, j + 1, memo))
            }
        }
        return helper(s1, s2, i, j, memo)
    }

    return lcsMemo(arr1.join(''), arr2.join(''))
}
```

Some test cases are:

```
console.log(commonChild('SHINCHAN', 'NOHARAAA')) //3 NHA
console.log(commonChild('AA', 'BB')) //0
console.log(commonChild('HARRY', 'SALLY')) //2 AY
console.log(commonChild('ABCDEF', 'FBDAMN')) //2 BD
```

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" does not tell us what you expect or what's actually happening.

Comment: I've edited my question, but as I can't see the test cases on HackerRank, I am unable to decipher why it is failing.

Comment: I'm off to bed, so I can't really look into this.  At a guess, it's an index problem, where you try to set `something[i][j]` when `something[i]` doesn't exist.  One bit of cleanup:  `const arr1 = [...s1].filter(c => s2.includes(c)), arr2 = [...s2].filter(c => s1.includes(c))`.  You don't need those odd `for` loops.

Comment: Maybe you can run it in your own machine to see the error. That would help us help you

Comment: Unfortunately, the test cases I have all pass, I am not sure what test cases are failing, since I cannot see them

Comment: what are constraints of the string ? When there is recursion involved, you might exceed maximum stacksize. You should try a sufficiently large random input to check if your code breaks in that situation. Apart from that I can't seem to find any logical flaws in your code.

Comment: I realized that in your code, you don't update memo if s1[i] == s2[j]